# Twitter search and earliest possible date

Tags: search, twitter

Can anyone familiar with the Twitter Search API tell me what the earliest possible Search date in (YYYY-MM-DD) format is?

Also, when using this date, is it necessary to omit any date limited query string parameters?

And does the order of query string parameters matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way Twitter stores and serves Tweets in their search API, the minimum date won't really matter.  This is because only the last 1,500 results for a given search are stored and served.  There's also some sort of time limit, where if you're using lesser-used search term or hash tag, Tweets will expire after [7 days](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search).

ETA: In practice, it seems Tweets are stored/served [longer](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=+%23nfl+until:2010-02-01+) than 7 days.

Comment: Wow, if true that's not taking real advantage of the power of search. I assume this is a server storage rather than performance issue. I assumed you could search back until the birth of Twitter..

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken it seems that if you use the offcial Twitter search page, you CAN search back further
ie
http://search.twitter.com/search?q=+%23nfl+since%3A2008-01-01

Does Twitter check to see what application made the original call and then throttle back the availability of some search parameters?

Comment: It is pretty lame, but it's tough to imagine how much (crap) data they have to deal with and the sacrifices they have to make.  And no, I don't think they throttle based on what application is searching... tweets I made on January 8th are not reachable through the search (using unique hash tags).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly search is limited to the previous 7 days, so it's right now - 7 days.